# ASP.NET MVC : how to run a stored procedure using LINQ syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

[image]I am trying to use Linq to Sql to execute stored procedure. I have been using the following syntax up until today, but from today it started giving me an error on all throughout the application. I get the following exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'
```

The code I used

```
return db.Database.SqlQuery<SchViewModel>("TaskList.TaskListSchedule").ToList();
```

```
//View Model
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TaskList.Models
{
    public class SchViewModel
    {
        public int TaskListItemID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ReportID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> MemberID { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
        public string FrequencyType { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
        public string Deadline { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CompletedDate { get; set; }
        public bool Missed { get; set; }
        public string OnTime { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on the database access technology that you are using, and is not related to Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: I have been using the following syntax up until today, but from today it started giving me this error on all throughout the application with the following message. System.InvalidOperationException: 'The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.' The code I used - return db.Database.SqlQuery<SchViewModel>("TaskList.TaskListSchedule").ToList(); --- I thought I'm using the syntax incorrectly

Comment: Any suggestion why I'm getting this error suddenly? or a fix please?

Comment: @Ven looks like it is trying to assign `null` to non-nullable property. Either make that property in `SchViewModel` nullable using [`?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) or populate value in database for corresponding field.

Comment: @Ven please post the `SchViewModel` definition and some sample data it is trying to assign.

Comment: Many thanks @Pirate, I've posted the view Model here.

Comment: `public bool Missed { get; set; }` looks like the only property that could be causing this.  None of the other properties are boolean.

Comment: why don't use "public int? ReportID" this way? is there any difference?

Comment: @Erman, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried changing the nullable datatype with ?. But this did not resolve the main problem.

Comment: Today the first record with a `null` value for `Missed` entered the database. I think somebody missed that...

Comment: @GertArnold infact you are absolutely right. Today is the very first day I received a Missed field with null. Thank you so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the boolean value in the stored procedure if the boolean value is null then you need to use the following condition in SQL.

ISNULL(Field, 0)

so it will be converted into boolean type.